# ALE Fix for a visual selection

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-ale

I am figuring out a way to apply linting to a visual selection of code. For example:

[image]

I **only** want to lint run `:ALEFix` on that section of code, and not the 100s (or 1000s) of lines of other code in the file. My first thought was doing something like:

- Copy the visual selection. `y`
- Option a new file and paste that in. `:vs tmp`
- Run `:AleFix` on that shortened file.
- Copy-all: `ggVG"*y`
- Close that file `:q!`
- Do `gv` to re-highlight the visual selection at the start.
- Paste in the copy-buffer `p`

What might be a better way to do that? And if the above seems like it might be the best way, what might be a clean function to do that with? (I'll try writing one myself as well...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little rough around the edges, but here is what I came up with (which I've tested and works for me):

```
function _AleVisualSelection()
    normal! gvy
    vs tmp
    normal!p
    ALEFix black
    normal! ggVG
    sleep 300m
endfunc

vnoremap    0   <Esc>:call _AleVisualSelection()<CR>y:q!<CR>gvp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim's built-in [`:h formatprg`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatprg%27) and [`:h gq`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq) for this.

You can set `formatprg` option to the fixer/formatter tool of choice, like:

```
:let &l:formatprg='some-program --some-flag'
```

Or with `set` syntax which requires escaping spaces:

```
:setlocal formatprg=some-program\ --some-flag
```

You may persist this setting in your vimrc, like:

```
augroup RangeFixer
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType python let &l:formatprg='some-program --some-flag'
augroup END
```

Or persist it in the appropriate `ftplugin` file (e.g. `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` or `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`), which removes the need for `autocmd`s:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim

let &l:formatprg='some-program --some-flag'
```

Once you have configured `formatprg` using one of above, then you can highlight the range you want to format, then press `gq`.

Comment: Or use `gq<motion>`/`gq<text-object>`